# Getting Value from Anchor tag after form submission

Tags: php, forms, anchor

I need to get the value in the anchor href attribute in another page after I submit the form. At the moment, I get the input value, but not what's in the anchor tag.
Below is my HTML form code:

```html
<form action="sample_login.php" method="GET" class="header_search_form clearfix">
    <input type="search" class="header_search_input" placeholder="Search for products..." name="search">
    <div class="custom_dropdown">
        <div class="custom_dropdown_list">
            <span class="custom_dropdown_placeholder clc">All Categories</span>
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
            <ul class="custom_list clc">
                <li><a class="clc" href="#">All ikram</a></li>
                <?php 
                require_once 'db.php';

                $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT category_id, category_name FROM category";
          $result = $con->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '
                <li><a href="shop.php?category_id='. $row['category_id'] . '"  class="clc" >'. $row['category_name'] . '</a></li>';
            }?>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="header_search_button trans_300" value="Submit" name="btn" id="btn"><img src="images/search.png" alt=""></button>
</form>
```

Comment: the raw HTML does not submit with the inputs ... if you need that information you need to include a hidden input with the information and a name that you can parse on the server side

Answer (score 0):

You either need to add a hidden element and set it’s name to whatever and the value must be the anchor tag href attribute, or you can perform an Ajax submission request abd set the request data to the form serialized plus the anchor href attribute value.